# compilation error about exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, g++

I met some compilation error but do not know what the problem is. The code seems not use exception, but the error is about it.

```
//in misc.h:
char *basename(char *name); // line 94

// in misc.cc:
char *basename(char *name) {   // line 12
  char *result = name;  
  while(*name) {  
    if(*name == '/') result = name + 1;  
    name++;  
  }  
  return result;  
}
```

Compilation error

```
g++ -pipe -W -Wall -fopenmp -ggdb3 -O2  -c -o misc.o ../../src/misc.cc  
../../src/misc.cc: In function ‘char* basename(char*)’:  
../../src/misc.cc:12: error: declaration of ‘char* basename(char*)’ throws different exceptions  
../../src/misc.h:94: error: from previous declaration ‘char* basename(char*) throw ()’  
make: *** [misc.o] Error 1
```

Does someone have some clue? Thanks and regards!

---

EDIT:
Files included in misc.h are

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <cmath>  
#include <fstream>  
#include <cfloat>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>
```

---

EDIT:
    in misc.i generated by -E option,

```
extern "C++" char *basename (char *__filename)  
     throw () __asm ("basename") __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));  
extern "C++" __const char *basename (__const char *__filename)
     throw () __asm ("basename") __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
# 640 "/usr/include/string.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/string3.h" 1 3 4
# 23 "/usr/include/bits/string3.h" 3 4
extern void __warn_memset_zero_len (void) __attribute__((__warning__ ("memset used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters")));
# 48 "/usr/include/bits/string3.h" 3 4
extern __inline __attribute__ ((__always_inline__)) __attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__, __artificial__)) void * 
memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, __const void *__restrict __src, size_t __len) throw ()  

{  
  return __builtin___memcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __builtin_object_size (__dest, 0));  
}  
...  
# 641 "/usr/include/string.h" 2 3 4  
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be picking up the definition of basename() from libgen.h.  On my OpenSUSE system, the version in libgen.h is defined with "throw ()" at the end (via the __THROW macro).

One thing you can try is to tell gcc to only run the preprocessor stage by adding the -E flag and then search for basename to see what is being defined:

```
g++ -pipe -W -Wall -fopenmp -ggdb3 -O2  -E -o misc.i ../../src/misc.cc
```

If that is happening, you'll either need to drop the include of libgen.h, match the throw specifier or change the name of your function.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel. So I change the name of my function and now I can compile it successfully. Still wondering though. I don't explicitly include libgen.h in any of the source files. So is it implicitly included in every C++ program and g++ or it is some other system library? Is it possible to find out which system library file making the confusion?

Comment: C requires that headers are independent; C++ does not.  So, any C++ header can include any other - and that may be what is happening.  Use the preprocessor only suggestions to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! By "C requires that headers are independent" do you mean in C a header cannot include another header? What can it say when preprocessing is successful while the compilation gives error like mine?

Comment: @Tim - to find out who is including libgen.h, first you should just run the preprocessor (using the -E flag mentioned in my answer).  Then look at the file generated (misc.i as done in my example) and look for a line like "# _number_ /path/to/libgen.h (note that _number_ will be a number and not the text _number_).  Then look at the line just before that line which should mention the header file including libgen.h.

Comment: ＠Samuel: Thanks! Did not find "libgen.h" in misc.i. How does one know which library could also declare the same function as mine?

Comment: @Tim - do you see basename() anywhere in misc.i?

Comment: Yes, Samuel. See my edit to the post. So what it can tell about which library file also has defined the same function? Is it string.h?

Comment: @Tim - to definitely tell, I would need to see some data that comes before the definition of basename.  Specifically, you want to look at the *last* "# linenumber file" that comes *before* the definition of basename.  The file mentioned there is your culprit.

Comment: @Tim - I just looked on my system and see a definition of basename in string.h, so that is your culprit.  It's hard to drop string.h as it's so common, so renaming basename() is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

"  ../../src/misc.h:94: error: from previous declaration ‘char* basename(char*) throw ()’  "

I'm reading that as having been declared twice, once with throw() and once without.

Comment: "basename" is only defined once in misc.h, and no "throw" in the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

Compiles for me, same flags.
g++ (Gentoo 4.3.4 p1.0, pie-10.1.5) 4.3.4

Your error says that there is a declaration of ‘char* basename(char*) throw ()’

try opening misc.h and searching for throw in the entire file, to see if you put the throw in yourself and just forgot about it.

Comment: Did not find "throw" in misc.h and misc.cc.